# How do I retrieve the description of an underlying error in Swift?

Tags: swift

Given that I have the following Swift error:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "UNKNOWN_ERROR" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=UNKNOWN_ERROR, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002dfa430 {Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600002dfa490 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=100 "Authentication Failed" UserInfo={NSMultipleUnderlyingErrorsKey=(
    "Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=2 \"An unknown error occurred. Please try again.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred. Please try again.}",
    "Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7003 \"(null)\""
), NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication Failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The authentication failed.}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred, NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception}}}
```

The `localizedDescription` for this error is `UNKNOWN_ERROR`, however I would like to retrieve the underlying error called `Authentication Failed`.

How can I retrieve this description in Swift?

Comment: cast as NSError and get the userInfo dictionary

Comment: Sometimes just displaying error (no localised description) gives more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code gives the last underlying error.

```
extension NSError {
    
    var lastUnderlyingErrorDescription: String {
        if let underlyingError = userInfo[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] as? NSError {
            return underlyingError.lastUnderlyingErrorDescription // Recursion 
        }
        // LocalizedFailureReason is often - but not always - more expressive than localizedDescription.
        return localizedFailureReason ?? localizedDescription
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Even better, perhaps: https://github.com/justeat/iOS.ErrorUtilities/blob/master/ErrorUtilities/NSError%2BChaining.swift